# Suppose a sequence's subsequences have at least one subsubsequence that converges almost surely to $X$. Prove convergence in probability

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Probability with Martingales

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

What I tried:

'only if'

Suppose a sequence converges in probability to $X$. By $d$ there exists a subsequence that converges almost surelyto $X$. Then by $a$, the subsequence converges in probability to $X$. Then by $d$, there exists a subsubsequence that converges in probability to $X$.

'if'

Suppose a sequence's subsequences have at least one subsubsequence that converges almost surely to $X$.

No idea. Hint please. Also, is the 'only if' part right?

Comment: Assume it does not converge in probability. Then it does not converge a.s.. Try to construct a subsequence which has no a.s. convergent subsequence.

Comment: @menag you mean subsubsequence?

Comment: a subsequence of the subsequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "only if" part is correct.

For the "if" part: try to argue by contradiction. This is a classical argument which is used also to prove that a sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ if and only if each subsequence contains a subsubsequence which converges to $x$ (in a generic metric space).

Comment: oh then if one knows that concept from analysis then it looks pretty easy? we deduce that the sequence converges to $X$ almost surely. hence it converges to $X$ in probability...?

Comment: Exactly, I would prove the a.s convergence of the sequence, which, as you pointed out above, is stronger than the convergence in probability.